# Access xinput events, particularly pen pressure, in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, tablet, pointer-events, stylus-pen

I've been searching for a cross platform api to read multitouch and pen/stylus input for Node.JS using Electron. I've tested Pointer Events Polyfill, which fails to detect pressure on my tablet pc (Thinkpad Yoga) for both Windows 10 and ArchLinux (i3wm, x11). Hammer.js lacks pen input and node-hid doesn't have an effective means for determining what is stylus input. However, Wacoms WILL sdk seems to cover what I'm looking for, however I can't think of a way to implement it into an application built with Electron.

Does anyone have an idea on a possible way to read xinput data with classifications?